# Was After Man ever adapted for TV or film?

Tags: after-man

Were the books *After Man* or *Man After Man* ever made into a TV show or a documentary movie?

I don’t mean the documentary *The future is Wild*, mind you. Maybe as a variant of the usual “time machine" style stories?

Comment: Kind of hard to prove a negative, but I'd go with no, from the results of [this query](https://www.google.com/search?ei=xNtgW9DfMM6ukwXF77jQDg&q=after+man+dixon+dougal+site%3Aimdb.com+-wild&oq=after+man+dixon+dougal+site%3Aimdb.com+-wild&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4234.5304.0.5405.6.6.0.0.0.0.59.276.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.KYEk5voxcVw). However, _Prehistoric World_ (1993) shows up and apparently features the author. You might want to check the thing out ([trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKINLclsdco))

Comment: [*Alien Planet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Planet) — based on Wayne Douglas Barlowe's book [*Expedition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_(book)) — is similar, if you thought you saw a video version of Dougal Dixon's [*After Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Man).

Comment: No @Gaultheria I don’t remember seeing a video version, sorry

Comment: @Jenayah - I find that it helps to actually ask the person in question. They're usually the best source of info about their own works.

Comment: @Valorum as it happens, not all of us are good friends with said author ;D but I can't deny that, as it's something I tend to do (in an other context)

Comment: Cheers for the acceptance. Glad you liked the answer.

Comment: @AbrahamRay - Couple of questions you might be interested in; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199154/what-was-the-fate-of-marley-in-a-christmas-carol-and-beyond and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199158/are-the-encyclopedia-of-xanth-and-ghost-of-a-chance-books-part-of-the-offici

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked my good friend Dougal Dixon (the author of *After Man*) this question and he was kind enough to point me toward a low-budget Japanese documentary production from the early 2000s.

You can view the full series [here](https://m.youtube.com/user/manafterman/videos)

---

This appears to be the only (other) derivative work whether TV, Film or written.

Comment: Now all that's left for you to do is learn Japanese :)

Comment: @Jenayah - What's annoying is that the non-voiceover bits are in English and then **dubbed over with Japanese.**

Comment: That's not worse than the _Ultraman_ 60s TV show where the English dubbing was not only awful, but sometimes just randomly absent, and you were left with no idea of what was said in Japanese. Fortunately, most 60s _kaiju_ plots do not really require much understanding of what's being said... :)