# What was the fate of Marley in A Christmas Carol (and beyond)?

Tags: a-christmas-carol

In *A Christmas Carol* Scrooge is visited by the ghost of his former partner Jacob Marley. Poor Jacob is covered in chains and shackles and seems to be in a very sore state.

> *“You are fettered,”* said Scrooge, trembling. *“Tell me why?”*
>
> *“I wear the chain I forged in life,”* replied the Ghost. *“I made it link by link, and yard by yard; I girded it on of my own free will, and of my own free will I wore it. Is its pattern strange to you?”*

**After his brief time with Scrooge we don't see him again. Is there any indication of his *ultimate* fate?**

[image]

Comment: Was it not implied he went to hell?

Comment: @Wooden13 - If you can provide a quote that backs that up, you've got the makings of an excellent answer

Comment: @Wooden13 - For the record, I'm pretty sure you're *wrong*, but I'd love you to prove otherwise

Comment: @Paulie_D - I see a lot of weasel words; Inferred, implied, etc.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Well, Christian mythos allows for more outcomes after death than a simple binary choice between Heaven and Hell

Comment: Ahh yes...found the relevant passage....not sure how you would describe it but it kind sounds like **a** hell.

Answer (score 11):

His spirit is *doomed* to travel the earth to see, in death, what it missed in life.

There is *no* indication that there is anything that Marley can do so change this situation.

> “It is required of every man,” the Ghost returned, “that the spirit within him should walk abroad among his fellow-men, and travel far and wide. And if that spirit goes not forth in life it is condemned to do so, after death. **It is doomed to wander through the world, oh woe is me!—and witness what it can no longer share**, but might have shared on earth, and turned to Happiness!”
>
> <sup>*A Christmas Carol - Marley's Ghost* - Charles Dickens</sup>

Further...

> “Seven years dead,” mused Scrooge. “And travelling all the time?”
>
> “The whole time,” said the Ghost. “No rest, no peace. **Incessant torture of remorse**.”

Comment: One man's hell is another man's heaven. Or, doesn't this sound similar to watching TV 24-7?

Answer (score 6):

### Marley will (eventually) receive absolution and enter the Kingdom of Heaven.

Marley's state in *A Christmas Carol* is one of *[purgatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purgatory)*, a ghostly apparition condemned to walk the Earth wrapped in chains that represent the various sins he committed in life (notably usury and avarice) until he's absolved himself of those sins through a mixture of [penitence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penance#Christianity), [abasement](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/abasement) and [mortification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortification_in_Roman_Catholic_teaching#The_salvific_meaning_of_suffering). **He describes his punishment not as the punishment of Hell, but rather as a ["*penance*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolution) which, by its very definition, will inevitably lead to his receiving absolution and thus gain entry into Heaven.**

> *“How it is that I appear before you in a shape that you can see, I may not tell. I have sat invisible beside you many and many a day.”*
>
> *It was not an agreeable idea. Scrooge shivered, and wiped the perspiration from his brow.*
>
> *“That is no light part of my **penance**,” pursued the Ghost. “I am here to-night to warn you, that you have yet a chance and hope of escaping my fate. A chance and hope of my procuring, Ebenezer.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[A Christmas Carol - Gutenberg Text](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46/46-h/46-h.htm)</sup></sub>

We find Marley only a few years into his punishment and feeling very sorry for himself. He's convinced that there's insufficient time left *before doomday* for him to pay sufficient penance for his actions (to receive absolution) but I think we can treat this as hyperbole. He's got a very long way to go, but he'll get there eventually.

> *“Oh! captive, bound, and double-ironed,” cried the phantom, “not to know, that ages of
> incessant labour by immortal creatures, **for this earth must pass into
> eternity before the good of which it is susceptible is all developed.**
> Not to know that any Christian spirit working kindly in its little
> sphere, whatever it may be, **will find its mortal life too short for
> its vast means of usefulness. Not to know that no space of regret can
> make amends for one life’s opportunity misused! Yet such was I! Oh!
> such was I!”***
>
> <sub><sup>[A Christmas Carol - Gutenberg Text](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46/46-h/46-h.htm)</sup></sub>

Comment: As Hamlet's father put it, "*I am thy father's spirit, 
Doomed for a certain term to walk the night, 
And for the day confined to fast in fires, 
**Till the foul crimes done in my days of nature**
**Are burnt and purged away***