# Are the 'Encyclopedia of Xanth' and 'Ghost of a Chance' books part of the official Xanth canon?

Tags: xanth

Although Piers Anthony is listed as the sole author on all 41 [Xanth novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth), another author, Jody Lynn Nye also wrote two additional books ([*Encyclopedia of Xanth*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/99451.Encyclopedia_of_Xanth) and [*Ghost of a Chance*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15481.Ghost_of_a_Chance)) set in the same fictional universe

All of the other Xanth books seem to be part of the same *internal continuity*. Does this apply to the two books named above and was Piers Anthony involved in their writing in any way, perhaps as a co-author or a consultant?

Comment: inspired by [this](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/7984/the-canonicity-of-the-encyclopedia-of-xanth) unwanted and unloved question on Lit:SE ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked my good friend Piers Anthony this question. I'm sure he won't mind me sharing his response.

> "*Jody-Lynn Nye wrote two Xanth novels with my permission, but **they are
>   not part of the official series. I was not involved in their writing**.
>   The other was Ghost of a Chance. She and I collaborated on [The Visual
>   Guide to Xanth](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/442122.Piers_Anthony_s_Visual_Guide_to_Xanth)*".
>
> <sub><sup>Via Email - Emphasis mine</sup></sub>